# How can I control whether opening curly brackets start on a new line with a .editorconfig in VS Code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, editorconfig

I am using VS Code as my editor. I have installed the 'EditorConfig for VS Code' extension. I have added an .editorconfig file to my root project. This is the code in the .editorconfig file:

```
root = true

[*.c]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
insert_final_newline = false
brace_style = attach
```

The following is the C-file (called main.c) that I want to format by using designated shortcut to apply formatting to the C-file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double fun(double x, double n)
{
    return pow(x, n);
}

int main()
{
    printf("Please write a base number:\n");
    double base, exponent;
    scanf("%lf", &base);
    printf("Write a exponent number:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &exponent);
    printf("The numbers %lf and %lf gives: %lf \n", base, exponent, fun(base, exponent));
}
```

The C-file (called main.c) is located within the root-folder as .editorconfig file. Thus,

```
Root
|-- .editorconfig
|-- Project A
    |-- main.c
```

I want to be able to make opening brackets be positioned on same line. The property **brace_style** should ensure brackets being positioned on same line. Unfortunately they keep being moved to new line. I can change property of **indent_size** to say 8, and these changes will then be formatted in the main.c file. Thus, there is "connection" between the main.c file and the .editorconfig file. It just don't want to format the brackets to same line.

Comment: show before and after example code so it's clear what you are talking about.

Comment: Tried to update the problem explanation. Is it sufficient?

Comment: It is a good idea to insert a final new line. It is a requirement of ISO C. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline

Comment: @user7860670 they're asking about newline before opening bracket- not at end of file.

Comment: @starball Yes, but there is `insert_final_newline = false` line in config.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of VS Code's EditorConfig extension supporting a `brace_style` property. [`EditorConfig.EditorConfig`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig) documents that it uses the [editorconfig npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/editorconfig), (at the time of this writing), its only supported properties are `indent_style`, `indent_size`, `tab_width` `end_of_line` (on save), `insert_final_newline` (on save), and `trim_trailing_whitespace` (on save).

I tried googling for the `brace_style` property and found [this JetBrains documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/EditorConfig_JAVA_SCRIPT_BracesPageSchema.html), so I wonder if you got it from a JetBrains IDE and assumed it was something you could use with any editor, when in fact- it's a editor extension. See also https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/issues/199#issuecomment-72388652.

If the EditorConfig extension for VS Code is *adding* those newlines, that's weird. If you just want it to get *rid* of them if they're already there, since the VS Code extension you're using comes from the EditorConfig maintainers, you'll either need to find a different extension, ask them to implement something that [they've already said doesn't make sense to be universal](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/issues/199#issuecomment-72388652), or wait for their [idea for a proposed domain specific property](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties#ideas-for-domain-specific-properties) "`curly_bracket_next_line`" to get decided upon (you may find issue tickets related to that [here](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aeditorconfig%2Feditorconfig+%22curly_bracket_next_line%22&type=issues)).